# Scrollbar for particular textview inside the RecyclerView is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

In the fragment,I want to scroll the TextView inside the RecyclerView so i put Scrollbar inside RecyclerView but its not working in mobile but works well in emulator and also tried nested scrollview but have the same problem.

What could i do if i want to scroll the particular textview inside the Recyclerview

ex.There are multiple attributes inside the recyclerview ex. imageview for user photo textview for user name and textview for user details as the user details field is lengthy i want to scroll this field seperatly

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bodyScroller"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="false">

<com.user.consulting_implantologist.MyText2
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/DrDetail"
    android:text="Detail"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorApp" />
   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Show some screenshots please.

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: ex.There are multiple attributes inside the recyclerview ex. imageview for user photo textview for user name and textview for user details as the user details field is lengthy i want to scroll this field seperatly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Layout.xml file u can use below code :

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scrollText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="long_text"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
    </ScrollView>
```

Below code is used in you **`ViewHolder`** file :

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            scrollText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.scrollText);
            scrollView = (ScrollView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);


            scrollText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            //Enabling scrolling on TextView.
            scrollText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview view has defualt scrollable behaviour so remove scrollbar  from inside of recyaclerview

Comment: yes you are right but i also want to scroll the textview seperately inside the recyclerview.

Comment: what you want to archiev i am not getting can you elebrate or given any example

Comment: There are multiple attributes inside the recyclerview ex. imageview for user photo textview for user name and textview for user details as the user details field is lengthy i want to scroll this field seperatly